# How to import two projects in Eclipse, like one

Tags: java, eclipse, svn

I have problem with importing two Java projects in eclipse like one.

I have one zipped file with 7z extension.

Zipped file structure:

trunk ->

- Server -> all server files
- Datapack -> all datapack files

So, extract files from zipped folder and trying to import trunk folder to eclipse and i get two different projects (Server and Datapack) and i can't apply diff patch, becouse thease two projects should be in trunk folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The other suggested answers so far will destroy the configurations that are already in each project.  You can avoid this problem by importing the two projects separately and adding one project to the other project's build path.  Specifically, try these three steps:

```
1.) Import both projects separately into eclipse
2.) Right click on the server project in eclipse, select Build Path...Configure Build Path
3.) Add the datapack project to the server project's build path.
```

You will then be able to access all of the `datapack`'s functionality from within the `server` project, as if the projects were merged.

This approach will retain any pre-existing project configurations that may be essential to the project function.

Answer (score 0):

you can solve this by creating an empy project ! then copy both folders into sources , like this you have all resources in one project , unless you are using maven then you need to merge the pom.xml files

Answer (score 0):

You should try creating a new project and merge both projects into it.